# Usage of vhdl-mode's vhdl-compose-place-component function

Tags: functions

The command `vhdl-compose-place-component` is supposed to create the text to place a component. I can't figure out how to specify which component it places, though. Right now, when I use it, it places a random component that I don't want it to. Here's the M-x describe-function:

```
vhdl-compose-place-component is an interactive compiled Lisp function
in ‘vhdl-mode.el’.

It is bound to C-c RET C-p, <menu-bar> <VHDL> <Compose> <Place
Component>.

(vhdl-compose-place-component)

Place new component by pasting current port as component declaration and
component instantiation.
```

Does anyone know how to specify which component it should place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You have to select the port map by entering into it, and doing:

`M-x vhdl-port-copy`

After that, you can place the component, or create the testbench with

`M-x vhdl-port-paste-testbench` in a new testbench file.